# Extending notion of even and odd subsequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology

For any sequence $\{ x_i \}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ we have the notion of the even $\{x_0, x_2, x_4, ...\}$ and odd subsequences $\{x_1, x_3, x_5, ...\}$.

These are the subsequences modulo 2. Is there any vocabulary for the subsequences modulo any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

i.e. for $n=3$
we have $\{x_0, x_3, x_6, ...\}$ and $\{x_1, x_4, x_7, ...\}$ and $\{x_2, x_5, x_8, ...\}$.

Comment: None that I know of. If you needed to use the idea a lot in an argument you would be free to invent appropriate vocabulary.

Comment: @EthanBolker yes, I think the $0 \mod  3$ subsequence should be good enough

Comment: If you're okay with defining scalar addition and multiplication on sets (*i.e.* for $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ a set and $a \in \mathbb{R}$ a real number we define $aX := \{ax \mid x \in X\}$ and $X + a := \{x + a \mid x \in X\}$) then we can write the subsequence of naturals congruent to $a \mod{b}$ by $$(x_i)_{i \in b\mathbb{N} + a}$$

Comment: @Lemmon yes that's probably what I recall seeing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of series, these are sometimes called *trisections*. See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection

The term has also been used for sequences in Lengyel, Divisibility properties by multisection, available at https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/41-1/lengyel.pdf